# Subquery returns more than 1 row with between

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked a lot on the site to find the solution of this issue but I cant seem to find anything that relates to what I am doing.

```
AND (SELECT CDPrice FROM cd WHERE CDPrice BETWEEN $p1 AND $p2)
```

essentially this is an addition to a sql query which is why its AND SELECT.

CDPrice is the name of a column and cd is the name of the table.
Where is used to check if the value of the column is between $p1 and $p2 which are text box inputs.

my error is: Subquery returns more than 1 row

I'm not exactly sure what to do to remove another result.

Comment: the prob is that the subquery is returning all the cd prices that are between those values which is not allowed for a subquery, but to actually help you please post the full query, or atleast an approximate example.

Comment: Edit your question and show the whole query.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks I'll just change the way the form is input and do it another way.

Comment: Even if it returns single row, this query syntax does not look correct. Please post full query, some sample data and what you want as output